# Mongodb created date return null

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

When I create product createdDate return correct, but on update createdDate return null, I tried to implements persistable but still not working

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class BaseEntity implements Persistable<String> {
    @MongoId(value = FieldType.OBJECT_ID)
    private String id;
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdDate;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updatedDate;

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return StringUtils.isEmpty(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you instantiating this object?  I.e. `new BaseEntity()`? or some other way?  Also, why are you overriding `isNew()`?  I ask these questions to better understand what you're trying to do, but I think you might be running into this issue  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/1872

Also, you can use @Document at the class level instead of implementing Persistable.

Answer (score 0):

To get value for createdDate you need to add @EnableMongoAuditing to main spring class

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoAuditing